# Check the entries in a Table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my `postgresql` table, there are four columns `inc_id`, `expense_grp`, `money`, `year`. `Money` is either 1 or -1 .

```
inc_id expense_grp money year
100 grocery 1 2017
200 food -1 2017
300 grocery -1 2018
400 food 1 2018
500 grocery -1 2017
600 food 1 2017
700 grocery -1 2018
800 food 1 2018
900 cloths 1 2018
1000 food -1 2018
```

Now, we need to find the sum of `money` for an `expense_grp` in a particular `year`.

As an example,

Ex 1 :-

`money` sum for `expense_grp` `grocery` in the `year` 2017 is (1 + (-1)) = 0

Ex 2 :-

`money` sum for `expense_grp` `grocery` in the `year` 2018 is ((-1) + (-1)) = -2

Now, Ex 1 is balanced because sum is 0 but Ex 2 is not balanced because sum is -2 . If we want to make Ex 2 balanced then we have to remove both the entries from the TABLE. To make it balanced either we have to make the sum 0 or remove the entries.

Not always it is required to remove all the entries. Suppose, if sum is like ((-1) + 1 + (-1)) = -1 , then we can remove the entry with -1 , so the target is to make the sum 0 . There are two entries with -1 , so we can remove by any order. Randomly we can pick one -1 and delete it.

I am looking for two solution queries like,

`SELECT * FROM dataset (solution query will be added here)` It will only show the entries of an `expense_grp` where sum is not balanced in a `year`.

It should return,

```
inc_id expense_grp money year
300 grocery -1 2018
400 food 1 2018
700 grocery -1 2018
800 food 1 2018
900 cloths 1 2018
1000 food -1 2018
```

`SELECT * FROM dataset (solution query will be added here)`  It will show the balanced data that means after doing removal operation.

```
inc_id expense_grp money year
100 grocery 1 2017
200 food -1 2017
400 food 1 2018
500 grocery -1 2017
600 food 1 2017
900 cloths 1 2018
1000 food -1 2018
```

NOTE :- We have removed the entry `800 food 1 2018` to make the `expense_grp` `food` balanced in the `year` `2018` .

Also removed `300 grocery -1 2018` and `700 grocery -1 2018` from the TABLE because the Sum is -2.

One thing we have to consider here is that before removing a row, we have to see if it can be added into any other unbalanced `expense_grp` to make it balanced in a same `year`.

So basically what I want is that find all combinations of year and expense group where the sum of money != 0 Remove arbitrary records which cause the "imbalance" until the sum of money == 0

What is the recommended way to achieve this ?

Comment: I am quite unclear on what you are looking for in the result set.

Comment: Please check the table output. I have given my desired output

Comment: Balanced means sum should be zero. We have to make it zero by removing entries or adding entries from other unbalanced entries for an expense_grp in a year

Comment: The rules aren't clear to me. I mean the easiest thing would be just to delete all rows. Then everything (which is nothing) sure will be balanced. But I don't think you really want that. So what exactly are the rules which rows can be deleted?

Comment: Delete the rows which is causing unbalanced sum. Look into the value for expense_grp. When year is 2018, expense_grp is grocery then sum of money is -2. Which is unbalanced. So in that case we have to delete two entries.

Comment: How do we decide which row is causing the "unbalanced sum"? In your example  ((-1) + 1 + (-1)) = -1 there are two candidates.

Comment: In that case, we can remove the entry with -1 , so that +1-1 = 0

Comment: We can remove by any order.

Comment: So what you want is:
Find all combinations of year and expense group where the sum of money != 0
Remove arbitrary records which cause the "imbalance" until the sum of money == 0
Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want