# sum the values in a postgresql table and balance the records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have postgresql Table,

```
value tag
1 Tag_A
-1 Tag_A
1 Tag_A
-1 Tag_B
-1 Tag_B
1 Tag_B
1 Tag_B
```

We have a table with two columns `value` and `tag`. We want to arrange the table in a way that sum of values for each tag is 0. We can keep calculating the sum in any order for a tag. If the sum is not 0, then the last imbalance record will be added in other `tag`. Now, we will count the sum of other `tag` the same way. If it is the last tag and it has an imbalanced record then that imbalanced record will be deleted.

In our table for `Tag_A`,

```
1 Tag_A
-1 Tag_A
```

is 0, But third 1 `Tag_A` is making the `Tag_A` imbalanced. So, first, we will add this record into `Tag_B` (there is no internal order. It could have appeared anywhere). Modified Table should look like,

```
value tag
1 Tag_A
-1 Tag_A
-1 Tag_B
-1 Tag_B
1 Tag_B
1 Tag_B
1 Tag_B
```

In the above table `Tag_A` is completely balanced because the sum of values is zero. But in `Tag_B`,

```
-1 Tag_B
-1 Tag_B
1 Tag_B
1 Tag_B
```

is 0, but end record 1 `Tag_B` is making the `Tag_B` imbalanced. There is no other tag left to add this record. So, we will delete the leftover record. Final table should look like,

```
value tag
1 Tag_A
-1 Tag_A
-1 Tag_B
-1 Tag_B
1 Tag_B
1 Tag_B
1 Tag_B
```

I am looking for a solution in SQL. What should be the recommended way to do this?

I can find the sum of values for a particular table,

```
SELECT COUNT(value)
FROM foo LIKE 'Tag_A';
```

Comment: I believe I saw this same question several hours ago, and it got closed.  What about your question is different?

Comment: `count(value)` will not "sum the values" - it counts the number of not-null values. If you want to sum the values you need `sum(value)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, maybe it was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938301/check-the-entries-in-a-table-in-postgresql) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938004/balance-the-sum-of-values-in-a-json-in-nodejs)